# Custom context menu position with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a custom contextmenu in a table. It seems that with bootstrap and the class col-lg, the contextmenu position is not correct and it is not displayed next to my mouse when I right click on a cell.

I tried to set a style on the context menu with :

```
#contextMenu {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

But it doesn't change anything.

Have you an idea how can I correct this problem ?

You can find here a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/85296/) for my problem.

Comment: Just replace `absolute` by `fixed` or keep `absolute` but add `margin-top:-25px; margin-left:15px`

Comment: Perfect ! It works like a charm ! Thanks
I just can't put this post as resolved like it's a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @executable said, you need just to replace absolute by fixed in the css style.